# Java for-loop going past exit condition

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a for-loop that is running through an array of size 512 (index range 0 - 511). However, when i == 512, it continues into the loop anyways throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. The screenshot below shows my code when I run it in debug mode with the stop condition set to i == 512.

[image]

Anyone have any idea why this loop is continuing to cycle even after the exit condition is met?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @Jack, I posted it as a screenshot to include all the debugging information from the IDE.

Comment: that's not how you are supposed to post your code in SO. An image can add further details but code should be just code, not a screenshot of your IDE. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop condition is:

```java
i < frameSet * associativity + associativity
```

According to the debugger, the current values are `512 < 64 * 8 + 8` or `512 < 520`, which evaluates to true. That is why the loop is still running.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that. It looks like when I initialized validBits[] I set the size of the array to the number of sets rather than the number of sets * associativity. (8-way set associative cache with 512 sets should have 4096 frames, not 512)